# Calling a fuction after org capturing

Tags: org-mode

Is there a way to call a certain function *after* a certain org-capture template
has been run (successfully, ie. not aborted)?

Comment: Do you mean automatically (as in a hook function)? If so, say, so please.

Answer (score 6):

You can add a function to `org-capture-after-finalize-hook` to have it run after an org-capture entry has been either confirmed or aborted. Then, within the function, you can use the variable `org-note-abort` to test whether the template was run successfully (nil) or aborted (t), and `plist-get` with the variable `org-capture-plist` to test which template was being used. For example:

```
(defun tina/test-finalize ()
  (let ((key  (plist-get org-capture-plist :key))
        (desc (plist-get org-capture-plist :description)))
    (if org-note-abort
        (message "Template with key %s and description “%s” aborted" key desc)
      (message "Template with key %s and description “%s” run successfully" key desc))))

(add-hook 'org-capture-after-finalize-hook 'tina/test-finalize)
```

Hope that helps!