org-capture with IDs
I want some of my capture templates to create an org-id when creating a header.
The below is wrong; I'm using it to explain what I'm trying to do:
 (setq org-capture-templates
    (quote (
        ("w" "Work") 
          ("wm" "Meeting" entry
        (file+olp  "~/Desktop/iCatch/Now.org" "Work") (file 
    (file+function+olp "~/Desktop/iCatch/Now.org" "Work") org-id-copy (file "~/Sync/Templates/temp-meeting.org"):jump-to-captured t)

The idea is that when I use the meeting capture, it will execute and then call the function org-id-copy (which I use to create org IDs manually and copy them to the kill ring) at the end, giving the header an ID.
I don't want ALL capture templates to create org IDs (I recall there's an option to turn this option on). I also want the ID to be in the kill ring when I'm done so I can yank it if I need it somewhere else.
Is there a built-in way to do this? Or only if I write a function for it with hooks (I will need help for this). Thanks!

Related: https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/48533/calling-a-fuction-after-org-capturing - you can try the answer there but you might find that you need a different hook (perhaps org-capture-before-finalize-hook). If your version of Org mode is 9.6 or greater, then there is a newer method using a setting local to the specific capture template: do C-h v org-capture-templates and search for :before-finalize - this avoids the need to check which template you used, which is required in the method described in the answer to the linked question.

Please check what version of Org mode you are running (M-x org-version will tell you) and add that information to your question.

Here's an implementation that will work for Org 9.6 and later.
Add the following to your init file:
(defun my/org-capture-add-id ()
  "Add an ID property with a newly generated id to the current node.
Also copy it to the kill ring for future reference."
  (org-entry-put nil "ID" (org-id-new))
  (org-id-copy))

(with-eval-after-load 'org-capture
  (setq org-capture-templates
        
        '(
          ;; All your other capture templates with single letter keys
          ;; come first (if you have any of course).
          ;; ...

          ;; Header for all the templates with keys starting with "w"
          ("w" "Work-related capture templates")

          ;; "wm" template
          ("wm" "Meetings" entry

           ;; Store them in the following file under the heading "Work".
           ;;
           ;; For my testing convenience, this Org mode file contains
           ;; the code but is also the target of the capture - in reality,
           ;; the code is going to end up in the init file and the target
           ;; of the capture is going to be some other file.
           (file+olp  "~/src/emacs/se-emacs/82693/foo.org" "Work")

           ;; the template
           "* %?\n%a"

           ;; function to run in `org-finalize' 
           :before-finalize my/org-capture-add-id
           :jump-to-captured t
           )
          ;; other "wX" templates go here
          ;; ...
          ))

The important thing to notice is the :before-finalize property  of the wm template that specifies the function my/org-capture-add-id. When the wm template is invoked, the function will be run at capture finalization: it will then add an ID property with a newly generated id and it will copy that value to the key ring so that you can use it later.
You can copy the code above to your init file, but you'll have to change the filename and the headline under which the capture will be stored.

Explanation
Org mode added the capability to specify a function to be run at specific times during capture finalization in version 9.6. The doc string of org-capture-templates says this (among many other useful things - you should C-h v org-capture-templates and read it[1]:
...
 :prepare-finalize   A nullary function or list of nullary functions run before
                     ‘org-capture-prepare-finalize-hook’
                     when the template is selected.

 :before-finalize    A nullary function or list of nullary functions run before
                     ‘org-capture-before-finalize-hook’
                     when the template is selected.

 :after-finalize     A nullary function or list of nullary functions run before
                     ‘org-capture-after-finalize-hook’
                     when the template is selected.
...

The three functions (or sets of functions) are run at different time. The :before-finalize function runs with the buffer widened and the entry decrypted (if you use that capability), so I believe it's the best one to use when you want to modify the contents of the entry. It also works in my testing (but I did not try the other two).
The only thing that is not provided is the function to do what you want: that's what my/org-capture-add-id is for. It adds the required ID property and gives it as value a newly generated id. It then calls org-id-copy to save the new id in the kill ring as you specify.
If your Org mode is before 9.6, then these properties don't exist, so you'll have to use a clumsier implementation. Instead of describing it now, I'll wait to see whether your version is >= 9.6 so you can use the code above.

Footnotes
[1] But I can never remember it, so I end up rereading it everytime I have to change org-capture-templates. That's a good thing...
