# Update DEADLINE: time and to do state on parent header after org-capture finishes

Tags: org-mode, org-capture

I have a couple of org-capture templates that insert tasks/notes under a header called `re-organize`, I'm looking to update the to do state and deadline of that `re-organize` header after org-capture finishes.

to illustrate, let's say the current file content looks like this:

```
* header 1
* header 2
* header N
* DONE re-organize
DEADLINE: >a timestamp of yesterday at 5pm<
** task/note to refill 1
```

and then if I insert `task/note to refill 2` via one of my org-capture templates this should result in this file structure:

```
* header 1
* header 2
* header N
* TODO re-organize
DEADLINE: >a timestamp of today at 5pm<
** task/note to refill 1
** task/note to refill 2
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I would suggest adding some additional conditions to the question so that a custom function can be written and attached to an org capture finalize hook and only operate on the parent heading if said conditions are met.  Because the reader of this thread is presently required to guess what conditions may apply based upon the minimal working example, the answer will probably not be exactly what you are looking for.  E.g., the parent heading must contain the words ...; or, the parent heading must contain a certain tag, etc.  All we have now is the fact that it is DONE and it says "re-organize".

Comment: Alternatively, perhaps the capture template would **only** be used when you already know the parent heading must be updated; in which case, the answer may be slightly different ...

Comment: See also "*How can I make a post-capture hook run only for certain capture templates?*":  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/45270/in-org-mode-how-can-i-make-a-post-capture-hook-run-only-for-certain-capture-tem and  "*Calling a fuction after org capturing*":  https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/48533/calling-a-fuction-after-org-capturing